# 'Property user does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this state interface in my React app:

```js
const initialState: IVote | null = null;
```

in the beginning, it's obviously `null`, then I fetch vote list from the server and it has a key -> users. What I'm trying to do is map through and create `<li>` elements in my component. But getting this error.

> Property 'users' does not exist on type 'never'.

I browsed around before I decided to create a post here and I tried this and it didn't help:

1. I initialized app state as :

   const initialState: any = null;
2. listJSX = currVote!.users!.map(el => el.name)
3. listJSX = currVote?.users?.map(el => el.name)

Out of ideas.
Here is a bit of code:

```
import { useAppSelector } from "../../hooks";

const VoteList: FC = () => {
    const currVote = useAppSelector(state => state.vote)
    let listJSX = null;
    if(currVote)
        listJSX = currVote.users.map(el => <li>{el.name}</li>)

    return (
         <ul>
           {listJSX}
         </ul>
    )
}
```

here is a pic who error looks like[image: pic]
[image]

Comment: your `initialState` should have a key `users` which initalize as empty array. Currently you don't have that key in your object hence it is throwing an type error.

Comment: so I can't assign it to null? That what you are saying. I always have to keep same types but empty. As lets say userName: "",  not userName: null, or in my case not the whole state null, but object with key users: [] ?

Comment: Correct! `null` doesn't have any key so at the compile time it throws an error where it doesn't return 

const initialState = { users: [], // other keys with the default values when app is initialize. }

Comment: omgggggggggggggg. Is just so easy to check if data received from a server or not. You know if it's null then... now I have to check if some key is empty, or active.

Comment: Accordingly, you can set the value to initialState.